# split char array into chunks

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to split char array into chunks and write it in console.

I've created such code, that split char array into chunks by 1000 bytes:

```
int i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < lstrlenA(temp); i+=1000) 
{
    BYTE* conf = (BYTE*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), NULL, lstrlenA(temp) - i);

    conf = (BYTE*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), NULL, 1000);
    for (int d = 0; d < 1000; d++) 
    {
        conf[d] = temp[d];
    }
}
```

this code works perfect, but there is a problem. char array can be more than 2000 and less than 3000 bytes. so, if I try to cut 1000 bytes - I miss N amount of bytes.

How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

You should keep in mind the last block size. Also don't call strlen in loop, it is inefficient.

```
int i = 0;
len = lstrlenA(temp);
for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1000) 
{
    int count = (len - i) > 1000 ? 1000 : (len - i);
    conf = (BYTE*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), NULL, count);
    memcpy (conf, temp+i, count);
    ....
```

Ok, your version of inner loop would do logically the same:

```
for(...
    ...
    conf = ...
    for (int d = 0; d < count; d++) 
       conf[d] = temp[d];
```